# Importing external js library in Vue.js Single File Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following Single File Component in Vue.js.

The *plasmid* tag is meant to get rendered by the *angularplasmid.complete.min.js* file but isn't for some reason. Is this the correct way to import a library in a component?

I am restructuring an old Vue project to be better designed but I know that the *plasmid* tag renders on here (which doesn't use single file components): https://github.com/asselinpaul/dnaviewer/blob/master/app/index.html

Any help much appreciated.

```
<template>
<div id="DNA Plasmid">
    <h3>Plasmid Visualisation</h3>
    <div class="section">
        <plasmid id='p1' plasmidheight="800" plasmidwidth="800" v-bind:sequencelength="sequenceLength">
            <plasmidtrack id='t1' radius="200" width="55">
                <trackmarker v-for="(bound, index) in bounds" class='marker' v-bind:start="bound.start" v-bind:end="bound.end" v-bind:style="{ fill: bound.color }" v-bind:key="bound.start">
                    <markerlabel v-bind:text="bound.name" v-bind:vadjust='bound.vadjust' style='font-size:12px'></markerlabel>
                </trackmarker>
                <tracklabel v-bind:text="name" style='font-size:25px;font-weight:bold'></tracklabel>
            </plasmidtrack>
        </plasmid>
    </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
import './angularplasmid.complete.min.js'

...
```

Comment: This looks like an Angular library and I expect that you will have issues combining it with Vue because Angular and Vue will both be fighting over the template.

Comment: @BertEvans I tell Vue to ignore the template that pertains to the angular bit `Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['plasmid', 'plasmidtrack', 'trackscale', 'trackmarker',
    'tracklabel', 'markerlabel'
]`

Comment: Sure, but since this is a component, that HTML potentially doesn't exist on the page when Angular is initialized.

Comment: @BertEvans I don't know if I use Angular or just the visualisation code (from here: http://angularplasmid.vixis.com/usage-basic.php) since the angular portion of the code (manipulating the fields in the dom) is performed by vue.js. There is an example in the first answer's comment on how it works using a differently structured Vue.js program.

Comment: With a single file component (or any component) in Vue, the template is not rendered to the page *immediately*, it happens after the page is loaded. In your pre-componentized example, whatever your imported script does, the HTML is available on page load. However, with the component, the HTML is not available until *after* page load, and I doubt your imported script is monitoring changes to the page to know when it needs to render the chart. So you will need something to initialize the imported script *after* the component has rendered.

Comment: Solved by requiring the file when the component is mounted. Thank you @BertEvans !

Answer (score 2):

Solved by requiring the file when my component is mounted:

```
mounted: function(){
    require('./angularplasmid.complete.min.js')
  }
```

Comment: I'm glad this worked, but I wonder if there will be problems when/if the component is re-rendered (if it ever is).

Comment: interesting, at the moment it isn't but I see why it might fail.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can't reasonably combine angular functions with Vue. Plus, angular use [its own dependency system](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Beside, you can use import in a single-file component exactly the same way than in any script. But of course be sure that your imported script is actually exporting something (or is relevant to execute as a module, which is probably not the case here).

Here is a reminder of the syntax:

```
import defaultMember from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { member } from "module-name";
import { member as alias } from "module-name";
import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";
import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultMember, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Note that the commonJS `require()` and `module.exports` are also perfectly fine in a single-file component.

Comment: it works here (my previous non single-file-component attempt): https://dna.now.sh/ for which the code is here: https://github.com/asselinpaul/dnaviewer/blob/master/app/index.html

Comment: I think the problem is that the AngularPlasmid code is looking for the <plasmid> tag before Vue.js has populated the view.